# How to publish messages using MAM to my private tangle?

Tags: iota-network, tangle, masked-authenticated-messaging, javascript, legacy-protocol

I have a private tangle with 2 hornet nodes. I tried MAM using one of the devnet nodes by following the example on the official IOTA webpage. Can someone please tell me how do I publish and fetch messages from a private tangle?

I tried changing the const provider to 'http:// IP_of_node:port number' but this did not work.

Please find the screenshots of the code which I used for the devnet.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiW5k.png)[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about the legacy-network and it is a good idea to keep only Shimmer/ShimmerEVM and latest IOTA Chrysalis questions

Answer (score 1):

Provider URL does not point to your private tangle. You need to add the url to one of your private tangle nodes. And then from there you can try to fetch the information you sent to see if it really works.

Comment: Thank you. I have it working now.